# Symfony2: route for host name only?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

For an application just installed at a shared host all is well except for a request that has only the host name.  What should happen is to be directed to the login page or home page depending on authentication.  This is true in my Windows development environment for both prod & dev, and at a previous attempt to host the site in a FastCGI chroot'd environment.  I'm hoping for a .htaccess solution since I have no access to vhost.  I am, however, functionally illiterate with rewrite rules and my experiments have failed.

In sum, www.example.com loads only the host's "Coming soon" page.  www.example.com/home, for example, loads either home or login route.

#### .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

#### routing.yml

```
mana_household:
    resource: "@ManaClientBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check

login_path:
  pattern: /login

logout:
    pattern:   /logout

home:
    pattern: /home
    defaults:  { _controller: ManaClientBundle:Default:index }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root:
    pattern: /
    defaults:  { _controller: ManaClientBundle:Default:index }
```

Comment: I had tried that yesterday without success.  The failure now appears to have been browser-cache related.  Today, in IE rather than firefox, success.  Many thanks!